# tezos-node snapshot import command does not exist anymore?

Tags: node, snapshots

Just changed harddrive, and thought I would spin off a node from snapshot instead of copying .tezos-node folder, but it seems that the import operation does not exists anymore:

```
$ ./tezos-node snapshot import 694626-BKrv2G5sRNJW.rolling
tezos-node: OPERATION argument: invalid argument: import
Usage: tezos-node snapshot [OPTION]... OPERATION FILE
Try `tezos-node snapshot --help' or `tezos-node --help' for more information.

$ ./tezos-node snapshot --help
SYNOPSIS
       tezos-node snapshot [OPTION]... OPERATION FILE

DESCRIPTION
       The snapshot command is meant to export snapshots files. Several
       operations are possible:

       export allows to export a snapshot of the current node state into a
       file.

MISC OPTIONS
       --data-dir=DIR
           The directory where the Tezos node will store all its data.

       --rolling
           Force export command to dump a minimal snapshot based on the
           rolling mode.

ARGUMENTS
       OPERATION (required)
           Operation to perform. Possible value: export.
[...]
```

No mention of import, anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: using `$ ./tezos-node --version`
`d272059b (2019-04-08 09:57:21 +0200)`

Comment: There is an (old) version of mainnet where you can export snapshots but not import them. You should update your node (`git pull && make build-deps && eval $(opam env) && make`)

Comment: God... It couldnt be not up to date, as I checked out the repo yesterday. Sudden inspiration: `$ git remote get-url origin`
`https://github.com/tezos/tezos.git` !!! Correct repo is gitlab, not github, they should remove this old mirror...
Thanks @vect0r, add that as answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Hum, yes. The tezos sources are hosted on gitlab. It should be less confusing, I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that your node is not up-to-date. You should:

- Ensure the repository address: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/ (it can be checked using `git remote get-url origin`)
- update the node: `git pull && make build-deps && eval $(opam env) && make`